# OpenMP symbol information

Tags: openmp, libraries

I'm reading Intel VTune documentation about OpenMP and I found [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/openmp-analysis-lin):

> To analyze an OpenMP application compiled with GCC*, make sure the GCC
>   OpenMP library (libgomp.so) contains symbol information. To verify,
>   search for libgomp.so and use the nm command to check symbols, for
>   example: $ nm libgomp.so.1.0.0 If the library does not contain any
>   symbols, either install/compile a new library with symbols or Debug
>   Information for Application Binaries for the library.

```
nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
nm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0: no symbols
```

But now I don't know install/compile a new library with symbols or Debug Information for Application Binaries for the library.

Comment: Linking against intel libiomp5 would enable more vtune functionality, if you aren't interested in performance of libgomp itself.  If you do want to analyse libgomp, you will need to download its source code and build it with -g.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051354/cannot-locate-debugging-symbols-and-a-lot-of-idle-cpu-usage) question?

Comment: `libgomp` is part of the GCC compiler. Make sure that you download the sources for the same version of the compiler as the one you have installed.

Comment: Extending Hristo's comment, you can always download GCC sources and compile it with debug enabled (now I see that Tim already suggested that :) )