# Cannot locate debugging symbols and a lot of idle CPU usage

Tags: c++, opencv, profiling, intel-vtune, intel-parallel-studio

I'm new to VTune Amplifier and I'm trying to profile OpenCV with a very basic application. Following [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/605665) guide on recommended compiler options, I compiled OpenCV via CMake with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo` and `-DWITH_OPENMP=ON` so both `-O2` and `-g` options are included and OpenMP enabled. My testing OpenCV application is compiled with

```
g++ -I/home/luca/Dropbox/SURFSPM/opencvInstall/include -O3 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
```

via eclipse. However, when I try to analyze my application this is the collection Log:

```
Data collection is completed successfully
    Sunday, February 05, 2017 AM11:44:53 CET  The result file '/home/luca/intel/amplxe/projects/OpenCV/r000hs/r000hs.amplxe' is successfully created and added to the project OpenCV. 

Finalization completed with warnings 
    Sunday, February 05, 2017 AM11:45:01 CET  Result finalization has completed with warnings that may affect the representation of the analysis data. Please see details below. 
    Cannot locate file `[stack]'.
    Cannot locate debugging symbols for file `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1'.
    Cannot match the module with the symbol file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21': checksum is different. Make sure to specify the correct path to the symbol file in the Binary/Symbol Search list of directories.
    Cannot locate debugging symbols for file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6'.
    Cannot locate debugging symbols for file `/opt/intel/vtune_amplifier_xe_2017.1.0.486011/lib64/runtime/libittnotify_collector.so'.
    Cannot locate debugging symbols for file `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'.
    Cannot locate debugging symbols for file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0'.
    Cannot locate debugging symbols for file `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.3.1'.
    Cannot locate debugging symbols for file `/opt/intel/vtune_amplifier_xe_2017.1.0.486011/lib64/libtpsstool.so'.
    Cannot locate debugging symbols for file `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.1'.
    Cannot locate debugging symbols for file `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1'.
    Cannot locate debugging symbols for file `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.1'.
```

In addition, as you can see from the following image, most of the time the CPU usage is in idle:

[image]

Which make me think that this warning messages are important and I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Time in idle is likely for the CPU waiting the OS to finish some background work (waiting for disk, ...) Additionally, if you add the metrics in the histogram, your run was very short (about 500ms). That does not seem to be representative... Can you try with something larger?

Comment: @Harald thanks for your answer. However testing my application on larger data (images), which would be more time consuming, is not a real case, since so big images are not going to be used in the real-world application. And I'm almost sure that if scales well with big data, it doesn't mean that it will with smaller ones.